# Nodejs Redis: Multiple queries in different redis databases with same client

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm not very experienced with Nodejs and its async ways.
I'm trying to query different databases of redis.

I have a simple function to get a key from a redis database:

```
function get_key(client, key, db, callback) {
    if (key) {
            client.select(db, function(e, s) {
                    if (e) {
                            console.log('client.select err: ' + e);
                    } else if (s) {

                            client.get(key, function(e, s) {

                                    callback(e, s);
                                    return s;
                            });
                    }
            });
    }

    return
```

}

And I'm using it to query multiple databases like this:

```
get_key(client, key1, 0, function(e, s) {
    if (s) {
            // do stuff with s;
    } else {
            debug('e: ' + e);
    }
});

get_key(client, key2, 1, function(e, s) {
    if (s) {
            // do stuff with s;
    } else {
            debug('e: ' + e);
    }
});
```

but it is not working working. But If I create different clients for each query, it works. I have queries in over a dozen databases, and wouldn't prefer to create a new client everytime I do a query.

Is there a better way to do this? the "node" way that I'm not familiar with? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Async functions take a callback function as a parameter.  The function returns close to immedately, and the callback is called after the work is completed rather than blocking the caller.  So your first call returns before its calls to redis are complete and the second call is being made immediately, which probably screws up the first call because they share the same client.

If you only have two calls to make, the simple answer is to put the second call within the callback of the first call.  If you need to make a lot of async calls in series, look into using [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) or some of the available libraries like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async).

Comment: So in the get_key() function the return at the end is executed before callback function is even called? Also, is there no decent way to do this in nodejs without using any external modules? Yes I have a lot of calls to make, and I'd preferably not want to use other libraries/modules. Is there no way in nodejs to do this cleanly?

Comment: It goes something like `if (key) start select request and return, continue select when response comes back, then call the callback with the results`. The idea is to not block Node's single thread waiting on the I/O operations to complete.  You can put as many calls inside of callbacks as you want without using a library, but your code can end up looking like a huge pyramid of brackets.  The libraries improve readability and provide structure, and fwiw they are not nodejs-specific,  for example promises are used in browser javascript as well.

Comment: Yeah, but I barely understand nodejs enough I wouldn't really prefer using another external framework only to improve readability. I think if this is the standard way to do things in nodejs, should they not probably include it in the standard libraray maybe. Anyway, thank you. I'll go ahead and use node-async for now.